# How to remove the word "index" in URL from the last segment using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to remove word index from my URL as below

from

```
https://domainname/what-we-do/index
```

to

```
 https://domainname/what-we-do/
```

I want to do this using `.htaccess` or anyhow.

Comment: Why is this tagged with "php", "html" and "css"? This is miss leading. Please remove those tags. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it's literally just that one URL then you can do the following using mod_rewrite at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(what-we-do/)index$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

The `$1` backreference contains the captured subpattern (ie. `what-we-do/`) from the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. This simply saves repetition in this instance.

If you needed this to be more generic and redirect `/<something>/index` to `/<something>/` then change the above `RewriteRule` directive to read:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/)index$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

This is a 302 (temporary) redirect. If this is intended to be permanent then change this to a 301 - but only when you are sure it's working OK.